# Is it possible to run a thin client in virtualbox?

Tags: x11, ssh-tunneling

I have a Mac laptop for work. I would like to keep my personal stuff off of my work computer. Obviously I can just ssh to my home computer and/or tunnel X using Quartz. But this always feels clunky, plus I don't get to use i3wm.

Is there a way to run something like a thin client using VirtualBox, where I can connect to my home machine as if I were sitting at the computer, letting me use my normal shell to login, and if so desired, startx?

Comment: VirtualBox creates a VM that has nothing but CPU, RAM and configured devices, so it is assumed that you install the OS inside. Thus, no thin client is possible.

Comment: If no thin client - is there any other option that would allow me to do what I want? i.e. login to my linux box (more or less) as if I were sitting there?

Comment: what exactly you would like to do? why simple X ssh tunnel is not acceptable?

Comment: It doesn't run i3, at least that I can figure out. I want the *entire* keybindings. VirtualBox provides that...

Comment: then you have no other option than to run some OS inside a VM, e.g. any Live CD of some Linux flavor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can't actually run a full-on thin client, you *can* do the next best thing - tunnel your entire X session. I found this solution at [LinuxJournal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/remote-window-managers).

```
xinit /usr/bin/xterm -- :1 &
ssh -fY remotehost /usr/bin/i3
```

(replace `/usr/bin/i3` with whatever window manager you prefer)

xterm can really be anything, but xterm is only about a 3mb install on Arch Linux. I also installed:

- xorg-xhost
- xorg-server
- xorg-xinit

(I may not have actually needed `xorg-xhost` to get this running).

I now have i3wm with all of my key bindings, and it works just like if I were sitting *at* the computer (plus some extra lag, of course).